# cellhight in tabulary - arraystretch doesn't work

Tags: math-mode, tabulary

I have a Problem with the combination of tabulary, math mode ( $...$ ) and arraystretch.

I have some tabularys and there is some text in it in math mode. The problem is, that the text is exactly as high as the cell hight, and I want there to be some space between the equation and the borders. Usually it works with arraystretch, but in this case it's not working (maybe it has something to do with using math mode?)

I'll try to give a minimal example of my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, DIV10]{book}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}


tabulary without arraystretch
\begin{tabulary}{0.3\textwidth}{|c|c|}
\hline
$ \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{27x^5y^9}}{3xy^3}$ & \\ \hline
$ \dfrac{\sqrt{4x^3}}{x}$&  \\ \hline
$ \dfrac{\sqrt{18x^4}}{x^2}$&  \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\vspace{1cm}

tabulary with arraystretch\{2\}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabulary}{0.3\textwidth}{|c|c|}
\hline
$ \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{27x^5y^9}}{3xy^3}$ &  \\ \hline
$ \dfrac{\sqrt{4x^3}}{x}$&  \\ \hline
$ \dfrac{\sqrt{18x^4}}{x^2}$&  \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}


\end{document}
```

You can see, that both tabularys are exactly the same:

[image]

I'd like to have a solution for this problem, where I can predefine the hight, not for every cell separately, because there will be a lot of tabularys in my document.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: `\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}`

Comment: tabulary with just `cc` columns and no `CLR` columns can not do anything very useful

Comment: Probably easier to use struts (assumes the `array` package) `\newcommand\test{\rule[-1.8em]{0.4pt}{4em}}` once ok (change `0.4pt` to `0pt`) and insert it in a column via `|>{\test}c|c|`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need tabulary for automatic column break and multicolumn - what do you mean with your comment that it's not useful the way i use it? \extrarowheight doesn't work the way I want it - it just fills the space above the equation (text should still be fully centered in the cell). 
Same with the \newcommand.
But thanks for your help :)

Comment: `tabulary` introduces new uppercase column types `C`, `L`, `R` that allow line breaking to an automatically determined width. You ar using `c` which is a single line entry not allowing linebreaking. If all columns are `c` then the table is just natural width and tabulary has no way to achieve the specified width in the first argument.

Comment: Ah, so I need to use capital letters -thank you :)

Comment: if you used `C` it would be a paragraph cell so you could use `\[...\]` instead of `$\displaystyle ...$` which would also improve your vertical space issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the arraystretch example does work, your factor was just too low to notice any significant difference. Try upping the factor, you'll see! :)

Comment: haha, you're right, thanks - but when I have vectors in my equation, the parentheses are always the exact same hight as the cell. Arraystretch works, but when i use parentheses [ \left( ... \right) ], no matter what equation/ size, the parentheses still touch the borders.